# Min cut of an undirected graph using random contraction algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

I have seen one implementation for the contraction of an edge in Kragers min cut algorithm:

We represent an undirected graph as a symmetric directed graph using the adjacency
list representation.

(STATMENT)Each vertex has a doubly linked list of edges adjacent to
it and pointers to the beginning and the end of the list. An edge u,v is represented
by two arcs, (u,v) and (v,u). These arcs have pointers to each other.

An arc (u,v) appears on the adjacency list of u and has a pointer to v.

1. For each (v,w) on the adjacency list of v, replace the reverse arc (w, v) by
   (w,u). This operation takes O(d(v)) where d(v) is the degree of v.
2. Append the arc list of v to the arc list of u. This takes constant time.
3. Delete v from V (G). This takes constant time.
4. Delete self-loops in the adjacency list of u. This takes O(d(u)+d(v)) time.

   i am unable to understand replacing the reverse arc (w,v) in the first step and what he means by (STATEMENT)?  i am familiar with only c language so please explain me with reference to only C

Comment: It means you shrink the two nodes u and v into one single node u. Hence you transfer all edges of v to u. Why he says only 'reverse' arcs, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For concreteness, we have a structure like

```
struct Arc {
    struct Arc *sym;
    struct Arc *onext;
    int edge;
    int org;
};
```

. Each undirected edge is represented as two arcs, one in each direction. The `edge` member stores the ID of the edge. The `sym` member points to the other arc of the same edge. The `org` member is the ID of the origin vertex of the arc (hence the edge is between `->org` and `->sym->org`.) The `onext` member points to the next arc with the same origin vertex; these arcs are linked together circularly.

For a very simple graph like

```
   4     5
1 --- 2 --- 3
```

, we have structures like this.

```
struct Arc a12, a21, a23, a32;
a12.sym = &a21;
a12.onext = &a12;
a12.edge = 4;
a12.org = 1;
a21.sym = &a12;
a21.onext = &a23;
a21.edge = 4;
a21.org = 2;
a23.sym = &a32;
a23.onext = &a21;
a23.edge = 5;
a23.org = 2;
a32.sym = &a23;
a32.onext = &a32;
a32.edge = 5;
a32.org = 3;
```

Now let's go through the steps.

#### For each (v,w) on the adjacency list of v, replace the reverse arc (w, v) by (w,u).

Let's let `struct Arc *a` be one of the arcs of the edge that we're contracting. We have a loop like

```
struct Arc *b = a;
do {
    b->org = a->sym->org;
    b = b->onext;
} while (b != a);
```

to go through the adjacency list of `a->org`. For each of the arcs that we encounter, we have to update the origin vertex to `a->sym->org`.

#### Append the arc list of v to the arc list of u.

We have to splice together the cycles involving `a` and `a->sym`. This is done with a swap like (UNTESTED!)

```
struct Arc *temp = a->onext;
a->onext = a->sym->onext;
a->sym->onext = temp;
```

.

#### Delete v from V (G)

This is out of scope for what I've described of the representation.

#### Delete self-loops in the adjacency list of u

We iterate through the adjacency list as before, but this time, we have to be a bit more careful, since we're mutating it. The basic loops look similar.

```
struct Arc *b = a;
/* look for a non-self-loop */
do {
    if (b->sym->org != b->org) {
        a = b;
        goto found;
    }
    b = b->onext;
} while (b != a);
/* everything is a self-loop; time to terminate the algorithm */
return;

found:
do {
    if (b->onext->sym->org == b->onext->org) {
        /* splice out b->onext */
        b->onext = b->onext->onext;
    } else {
        /* go to the next arc */
        b = b->onext;
    }
} while (b != a);
```

Note that all of this code is **UNTESTED**. An undeleted arc with the same origin is left in `a`.

Comment: Thanks,David.But i really need to delete nodes cos i have to contract edges till only 2 nodes are left and how to represent the graph in arcs given an adjacency list representation of 200 nodes. I mean say the graph has 5 nodes my input txt file has 200 rows like                   1->37->79->164->155->32->87->39->113 where (37,79,164,155...)represent nodes adjacent to node 1